# Using Twitter api in python to search for tweets in a given location

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to search for tweets originating from a given location. The code I am trying to use is at the bottom. This code works if geocode is commented out but returns nothing if left in. I know people have to allow their location to be shared for this to work and as such this should retun fewer results but 0 seems very low! Has twitter disbaled this function or am I not doing it right?!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tweepy as tw

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tw.OAuthHandler("#", 
    "#")
auth.set_access_token("#", 
    "#")

api = tw.API(auth)

try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication OK")
except:
    print("Error during authentication")

search_words = "hello"
date_since = "2020-1-1"

#tw=tweepy()

# Collect tweets
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q=search_words,
              geocode=[51.5074, 0.1278,'100mi'],
              lang="en",
              since=date_since).items(5)
for tweet in tweets:
    print(f"{tweet.user.screen_name}: {tweet.text}")
    print('-------')
print('Fin')'''
```

Comment: Have you trying with different latitide, longitude, radius (also in km instead of mi) combinations in your geocode? also try with ```q="*"``` (search everything) and check if it returns any value

Comment: Yes tried that, still no luck!

Comment: There are only a very small number of Tweets with exact location enabled, also the search using the standard API will only go back up to 7 days.